# Possible to point Clickhouse Table to a specific File Path?

Tags: csv, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am aiming at having a clickhouse table that is constantly updating rows and easy to export. I am considering having a Clickhouse table reference a path to a CSV file, similar to how dictionaries can reference an Absolute Path to a file under its source.

Is there a way to have it update accordingly to a CSV file? Instead of having to update rows all the time?

Comment: consider using the [File table engine](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/file/).

Comment: it says that 'It will use folder defined by path setting in server configuration.' what setting do I change, also how do I import an existing CSV of data to that folder. I tried but it doesn't seem to actually find it

Comment: `/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/`    ........     `<user_files_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/</user_files_path>`

Comment: what do i do with these file paths?